# Unable to access DBCONN after migration to EHP7

Tags: sql, abap, sap-basis

I want to access Unix Database from my SAP system.
I was using cl_sql_connection class to open the connection.
This class was working fine before the upgrade to EHP7.
But, now, I am unable to Access table DBCONN in any Stabdard SAP transaction (SE16, SE11...)

Following is my code, returning exception since EPH7 upgrade.

```
   * Fetch data from the ACMM application, using db-links.

        TRY.
        CALL METHOD cl_sql_connection=>get_connection
          EXPORTING
            con_name = lw_dbcon_name
          RECEIVING
            con_ref  = lo_sql_connection.

      CATCH cx_sql_exception .
 =>An exception occurred while opening SQL Connection 
    ENDTRY.
```

**Is their any other way through which i can connect to other Server?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can use the (older) variant of EXEC SQL.

But before you do, check the connection using ADBC_TEST_CONNECTION in SE38.

You could also get some more details by exploring the exception object you have. Here is how I usually do it:

```
TRY.
EXEC SQL.
  CONNECT TO 'ZUNIXDB_DBCON'
ENDEXEC.
EXEC SQL.
  OPEN dbcur FOR
    SELECT id FROM table
ENDEXEC.
CATCH cx_sy_native_sql_error INTO lr_cx_native_sql_error.
```

Now you have info like:

```
lr_cx_native_sql_error->get_text( )
lr_cx_native_sql_error->get_longtext( )
lr_cx_native_sql_error->sqlmsg
```

Comment: Trying ADBC_TEST_CONNECTION => I get error: 
Could not open connection G100-ACMM-INT                  .
sql error     12.154  occured:
con=2(p550i01-i01:1521/DBUISS10): ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: Also, I want to access the Unix Server (Oracle).. Please suggest something

Comment: I tried        EXEC SQL.
           CONNECT TO 'G100-ACMM-INT'
        ENDEXEC.  It's returning SY-SUBRC = 4

Comment: Check with your BASIS-people about the EHP7 upgrade. Did they change the host? Did they change network location? Give them the error message from ADBC_TEST_CONNECTION. It's quite clear that the SAP system isn't allowed to open the connection to the specified server/port. Either because of a firewall or unknown hostname.